# Converting JNI Java byte[] to C++ bytearray, returning 0

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I've a really big problem here. I am trying to pass a byte[] from Java to C++ and I am getting negative values after the conversion. I have determined the problem from having unique characters in the Java byte[] which after converting and doing a log, the values are either 0 or negative.

I have tried using a test byte[] of String characters and it works fine.

Here is my code, if it helps.

Java

```
public static native void SendMessage(byte[] message, int size); //size = message.length
```

C++

```
static void SendMessage(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jbyteArray array, jint array_length)
 {
     jbyte* content_array = (env)->GetByteArrayElements(array,NULL);
     //*env->GetByteArrayRegion(array,0,array_length,content_array); //tried this as well, same results
     LOGD("content:\n"); 
     for (int i=0; i < array_length; i++) 
     {
         LOGD("%d",content_array[i]); 
     } 

     //EDIT
     SendMessage(client, (uint8_t*)content_array, array_length); //<- could the problem be at the point where I convert it to uint8_t?

      (env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(array,content_array,0); 
  }
```

Output

```
content: 48
content: 23
content: 13
content: 56
content: 0 // <--- the problem starts here
content: -122
content: 0
content: 78
content: 32
content: -28
etc...
..
..
```

Now, using a simple test byte[]
Java

```
String test = "ABC";
byte[] message = test.getBytes();
public static native void SendMessage(byte[] message, int size); //size = message.length
```

C++

```
static void SendMessage(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jbyteArray array, jint array_length)
 {
     jbyte* content_array = (env)->GetByteArrayElements(array,NULL);
    //*env->GetByteArrayRegion(array,0,array_length,content_array); //tried this as well, same results
    LOGD("content:\n"); 
    for (int i=0; i < array_length; i++) 
    {
        LOGD("%d",content_array[i]); 
      } 
      (env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(array,content_array,0); 
  }
```

Output

```
content: 65 //this works perfectly
content: 66
content: 67
```

Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How are you obtaining the `byte[]` array in the problem case?  Is that also a conversion from a `String`?  If so, getting zeros and negative values in your log output may be perfectly valid.  It depends on the input characters and the encoding you are using to convert to a byte array.  If you are using `String.getBytes()` as with your simple text, you will be using the platform default encoding.  Your simple case shows that the default encoding is something ASCII-compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, I am not getting the byte[] from a String conversion. The byte[] is passed on from another source. I was able to convert it to String at the Java side for logging purposes and saw that it contained unique characters. 
You mentioned about different encoding. How to I set a different encoding from the platform default?

Comment: Use [String.getBytes(Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you think the problem is here.  In Java, `byte` is a signed type, so a negative value is not unexpected.  Jbyte is presumably an 8-bit signed C++ type to match.

The most likely explanations are:

- This is some artefact of the way that you are creating the byte array; e.g. you have encoded in UTF-8 (though the zero would tend to indicate otherwise ...)
- You've gotten the value of the `size` parameter incorrect:

  - For some reason it is larger than the byte array size.
  - The process that wrote stuff into the byte array didn't put `size` bytes into it.

---

It is worth noting that your JNI code doesn't check that `0 <= size < message.length`.  If this method is called with a `size` argument that is out of range, bad things could happen ... including segmentation faults, that would lead to a hard JVM crash.

Comment: thanks Stephen for the reply, no, I did a check to ensure that the size is correct. However, I didn't mention in my post (since edited) that I've cast the converted array to a uint8_t. Could that be the issue why the receiving end can only read up till the message up till 0? Does uint8_t support 0 and negative values?

Comment: The values for `uint8_t` range from 0 to 255.  However, since that is a C / C++ cast, you are *telling* the code to treat the values in the array as unsigned.  Anyway, based on the updates, I don't think that the problem is in the code you have shown us.